# iOS 8.1 UIImagePickerController in video mode - controls not responding

Tags: ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using this method to open the camera for video recording:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    UIImagePickerController *videoRecorder = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    videoRecorder.delegate = self;
    videoRecorder.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    videoRecorder.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
    videoRecorder.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    videoRecorder.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
    videoRecorder.showsCameraControls = YES;
    videoRecorder.videoMaximumDuration = 20;

    self.imagePicker = videoRecorder;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{
        //
    }];
}
```

The camera opens, I can start recording the video, but after I stop recording the **"Retake", "Play" and "Use Video" buttons are not responding**. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
Forgot to dismiss the image picker in delegate:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```